# Transform the row to a column and count the occurrence by doing a group by

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

am trying to transform the rows and count the occurrences of the values based on groupby the id

Dataframe:

```
id  value   
A   cake    
A   cookie  
B   cookie  
B   cookie  
C   cake    
C   cake    
C   cookie
```

expected:

```
id  cake    cookie
A   1   1
B   0   2
c   2   1
```

Comment: @sushanth am not getting that with multiple columns

Comment: `df.groupby('id)['value'].value_counts().unstack(level=1, fill_value=0)` or `df.pivot_table(index='id', columns='value', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0).rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()` or `pd.crosstab(df['id'], df['vaue']) .... `